# Searching a table that is created from Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a table that is create by the Codeigniter framework, and I also found a very good jQuery code for searching the table. The problem is that I can only search for the value that is in the first column.

However, if I create the table by HTML, the jQuery code works perfectly. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3384/

This is the code that I used to create the table by Codeigniter:

```
<?php
                            $tmpl = array (
                                'table_open'          => '<table id = "guestList" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">',

                                'heading_row_start'   => '<tr style="background: #E3EBEE; font-size: 15px;color: #1C75BC;">',
                                'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                                'heading_cell_start'  => '<th style="padding: 10px;">',
                                'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                                'row_start'           => '<tr>',
                                'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                                'cell_start'          => '<td style="padding: 10px;">',
                                'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                                'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                                'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                                'cell_alt_start'      => '<td style="padding: 10px;">',
                                'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                                'table_close'         => '</table>'
                            );
                            $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
                            $this->table->set_heading('Order#', 'Qty' , 'Customer', 'Order Date', 'Ticket Type', 'Price', 'Delivery Method');
                            echo $this->table->generate($record);
?>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
var $rows = $('#guestList tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
});
```

Comment: Is your HTML from fiddle HTML generated by Codeigniter? If not, compare these tables HTMLs and see differences...

Comment: @nevermind The HTML table is generated by Codeigniter, so I can't really find any difference